# Convergence in distribution and shifted pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition

Suppose $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ and the pdf $f_{Y_n}$ of $Y_n$ is defined by $f_{Y_n} (x) = f_{X_n}(1+x)$. Is it true that $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} X$?

By Portmanteau, $$\lim \mu_{X_n}(A) = \mu_X(A), \quad \text{for all $\mu$-continuity sets $A \in \mathcal \Sigma$},$$

if and only if that

$$E[f(X_n)] \to E[f(X)], \quad \text{for all bounded, continuous function $f$.}$$

Comment: No for example take $X_n$ a gaussian $(\frac{1}{n},1)$ converging in distribution to a gaussian $(0,1)$. Then $Y_n$ integrates to infinity over $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. doesn't define a distribution

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Sorry, I made a mistake. I wanted to ask that if $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ given that the pdf of $Y_n$ is $f_{Y_n} (x) = f_{X_n}(1+x)$? So, $\mu_{Y_n} = \mu_{X_n}$, and $\lim \mu_{Y_n} = \mu_{X}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$
F_{Y_{n}}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{Y_{n}}(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{X_{n}}(1+y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{1+a}f_{X_{n}}(x)dx=F_{X_{n}}(1+a).
$$

Comment: $Y_n$ does not converge to $X$ in distribution because $\lim_n F_{Y_n} (a) \not= F_X(a)$? In general, can I "visualize" convergence in distribution through density functions?

Answer (score 0):

$f_{Y_n} (x) = f_{X_n}(1+x)$ means that the distribution of $Y_n$ is the same as distribution of $X_n-1$. There is no reason for $X_n-1$ to converge in distribution to $X$. It clearly converges to $X-1$.

Comment: In general, can I "visualize" convergence in distribution through density functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "visualize"? If a sequence of pdf's converges to some pdf a.e. then under some addtional conditions CDF's also converge and weak convergence takes place. Do you ask on these conditions?